# Async is out of sync

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have a button that makes an http.get on click, and then displays some data, although my async/awaits seem to not be synchronized correctly.

For a reason I haven't quite figured out yet, `this.tabRows = file.contents` will be called before `loadDateFolderFileContents()` completes. Am I missing an `await` somewhere?

```
  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (!this.drawn) {
        if(!file.contents){
          await this.dataLakeService.loadDateFolderFileContents(file.parentFolder);
        }
        this.tabRows = file.contents;
        this.redraw();
    }
  }

  public async loadDateFolderFileContents(dateFolder: folder) {
    await date.files.map(async file => {
      file.contents = await this.getFileContents(dateFolder.name, file.name);
    });
  }

  public async loadDateFolderFileContents(dateName: string, fileName: string): Promise<any> {
    var url = this.buildUrl(dateName, fileName);
    var fileContents = {};
    await this.http.get<any>(url).toPromise()
      .then(contents => { 
        fileContents = contents; 
      })
      .catch(e => { 
        console.log(`Error retreiving file contents from url ${url}. Exception:${e}`); 
      });
    return fileContents;
  }
```

Comment: This: `return fileContents;` --> Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: this is weird, you are awaiting, but you have a ```.then```  which won't be waited for.   just let content = await this.http.get ....   and put it in a try catch

Comment: @KeithNicholas Thanks for the tip. I'm still new to the whole world of JS/TS + Promises, so I'm still struggling with them here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use await in a map, map will always return an array of promise. This is because asynchronous functions always return promises.
Since map always return promises (if you use await), you have to wait for the array of promises to get resolved. You can do this with await Promise.all(arrayOfPromises), after all promises are resolved, Promise.all returns a single promise.
below is your updated code

```
async ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (!this.drawn) {
        if(!file.contents){
          await this.dataLakeService.loadDateFolderFileContents(file.parentFolder);
        }
        this.tabRows = file.contents;
        this.redraw();
    }
  }

  public async loadDateFolderFileContents(dateFolder: folder) {
    await Promise.all(date.files.map(async file => {
      file.contents = await this.getFileContents(dateFolder.name, file.name);
    }));
  }

  public async loadDateFolderFileContents(dateName: string, fileName: string): Promise<any> {
    var url = this.buildUrl(dateName, fileName);
    var fileContents = {};
    await this.http.get<any>(url).toPromise()
      .then(contents => { 
        fileContents = contents; 
      })
      .catch(e => { 
        console.log(`Error retreiving file contents from url ${url}. Exception:${e}`); 
      });
    return fileContents;
  }
```

Comment: am I required to return from the loadDateFolderFileContents()?

Comment: @ChrisPhillips, It's your choice, shouldn't matter because async function returns it's own  undefined value wrapped in promise, if you don't return anything from it, otherwise whatever you are returning and here we are already using await inside the async function, so function will only return after asynchronous task is done

Comment: @ChrisPhillips let me know if it works or not

Comment: Thanks, this was the correct answer (as were some others below!). I'd have marked it sooner but I was heading out for the evening.

Answer (score 1):

map is not async so instead of:

```
await date.files.map(async file => {
...
```

try

```
await Promise.all(date.files.map(async file => {
...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
async ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (!this.drawn) {
        if(!file.contents){
          await this.dataLakeService.loadDateFolderFileContents(file.parentFolder);
        }
        this.tabRows = file.contents;
        this.redraw();
    }
  }

  public async loadDateFolderFileContents(dateFolder: folder) {
    await Promise.allSettled(date.files.map(async file => {
      file.contents = await this.getFileContents(dateFolder.name, file.name);
      return file;
    }));
  }

  public async loadDateFolderFileContents(dateName: string, fileName: string): Promise<any> {
    var url = this.buildUrl(dateName, fileName);
    var fileContents = {};
     
    try { 
        const contents = await this.http.get<any>(url).toPromise();
        fileContents = contents; 
        return fileContents;
      } catch(e){
          console.log(`Error retreiving file contents from url ${url}. Exception:${e}`);
      }
 
    
  }
```